# Using jQuery adding display:none; when something is true and at a certain size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, width, screen

I want to change a div in my code called text to diplay:none; as long as a div "#video-overlay-shadow and #video-overlay" are true and when the screen size is 740 when it is above 740 do nothing and when it is below 460. I started with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ window
var $window = $(window);

//display nav
var displayHide = true;

//on resize get widths
getWidths();
$window.resize(getWidths);

//set width of content to the needed widths
function getWidths()
{
    var browserWidth = $window.width();

    if ((browserWidth >=740) && (("#video-overlay-shadow, #video-overlay") == true))
    {
        //do somthing

    }
    else if((browserWidth >= 460) && (("#video-overlay-shadow, #video-overlay") == false))
    {
        //do something
    }
    else if((browserWidth < 740) && (("#video-overlay-shadow, #video-overlay") == false))
    {
        //do something
    }
}
//toggle nav
function toggleHide()
{
    $("#text").toggle();

}});
```

I wanted to know if I'm on the right track or can any one see errors in the code? The reason I can't use media queries is I need to make sure that "#video-overlay-shadow and #video-overlay" = true.

So just adding to what I said before I have tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var $window = $(window);

//display nav
var displayHide = true;

//on resize get widths
getWidths();
$window.resize(getWidths);

//set width of content to the needed widths
function getWidths()
{
    var browserWidth = $window.width();
    if(($("#video-overlay-shadow").length > 0) && ($(browserWidth >=740)))
                    {$("#hero-bg").css("display", "none");
                    }
                        else if(($("#video-overlay-shadow").length > 0) && ($(browserWidth <740)))
                        {
                        //do nothing
                        }

                        else if(($("#video-overlay-shadow").length > 0) && ($(browserWidth >=460)))//it exists
                        {
                            //do nothing
                        }
                        else if(($("#video-overlay-shadow").length <=0))
                        {
                        //do nothing
                        }
}});
```

But its still not working any ideas? Pretty much as it says in the code when video-overlay-shadow exists and the screen size is 740-460 I want display:none on #hero-bg otherwise do nothing. Its now just setting display:none; on #hero-bg all the time.

Comment: What do you mean by `#video-overlay==true`? Do you want to test for the existence of that element?

Comment: Ya I want to make sure it is being display on the page. There is a button on my page which when you click it, it overlays #video-overlay-shadow, #video-overlay on top of a banner that has two pictures on it. When you resize the page it looks grand until you get to 740 -460 so when it gets there I want to make sure that when  #video-overlay-shadow, #video-overlay are being displayed and your at 740-460 set display none for #text which is the name of one of the pictures in the banner.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just ask JavaScript if `#video-overlay==true`.  To test for the existence of an element in jQuery, find its length:

```
if ($('#video-overlay').length) {  // if no such div, length = zero = false
```

To test if an element is visible, use that selector:

```
if ($('#video-overlay:visible').length) {
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure what your trying to do here - but herre is what i would do to check if the elements exist

simply:

---

```
$('#video-overlay-shadow').val()
```

not

```
(("#video-overlay-shadow, #video-overlay") == false)
```

as your using a jquery object, instead of pure JavaScript so it should be contained with the $

```
if((browserWidth < 740) && $("#video-overlay-shadow").val() && $("#video-overlay").val()){}
```

so I hope thats closer to what your looking for, but more details would be useful

Comment: `$('#video-overlay-shadow')` will always be `true`, even if it's empty -- you need to test for the length of that jQuery object.

Comment: your right, both .val() and .length evaulate to false if no element, otherwise it returns a undefined object and evaluates to true

Comment: Check the new comment on the main question.

Comment: what is it your still having problems with? have you been able to make any progress?

Comment: Using the new code its now just setting display:none; all the time.

Comment: still having troubles please paste the new code you using so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

Why it can't be done using responsive web design?
In css-file:

```
/* start css */

// some styles for all devices with max-width 460px

@media (min-width: 460px) and (max-width: 740px) {
  #video-overlay-shadow, #video-overlay {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 740px) {
  #video-overlay-shadow, #video-overlay {
    display: block;
  }
}

/* end css */
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `$` for the two overlay elements.  Currently you are just testing a string, which is not what you want.  Assuming the overlays are just inputs, you want:

```
$("#video-overlay-shadow").val() == true && $("#video-overlay").val() == true;
```

If you are not storing any other truthy values in them, you can simplify this to:

`$("#video-overlay-shadow").val() && $("#video-overlay").val();`

Furthermore, I would store this value in a variable, rather than querying for it every time.